# Dojo functionality inside custom function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dojo

Using dojo I get an error: Cannot read property 'style' of null. Not always, but very often.
I try to figure out what happens. In my application I need to use dojo functionality inside my function, for example:

```
function updateModifySettings() {
    require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
          var drag = registry.byId("toolbar.modify.drag").checked,
              rotate = registry.byId("toolbar.modify.rotate").checked,
              resize = registry.byId("toolbar.modify.resize").checked,
              ...
    }
}
```

I'm very new in dojo and not sure how to write code above in the right way. I'm think that this piece of code causes error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "require" section should be outside of the function. If you want updateModifySettings to be a global function, try this:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    window.updateModifySettings = function () {
        var drag = registry.byId("toolbar.modify.drag").checked,
          rotate = registry.byId("toolbar.modify.rotate").checked,
          resize = registry.byId("toolbar.modify.resize").checked,
          ...

    }
});
```

Dojo switched to using the [Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD)](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) format in 1.7, which requires a new way of loading it's modules. You can read about how to build and reference Dojo modules in AMD [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/).

The [`window` object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) is the top object in JavaScript. By adding the functions to the `window` object, they are available globally.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain your answer or share any links where I can read about this.